# Proving that $(p - p^{5/6 + \epsilon}) + (1 - p^{1/6 - \epsilon}) \geq \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $p \in \mathbb{P}$ be an odd prime and $\displaystyle 0 < \epsilon < \frac{1}{6}$. How can I show that $\displaystyle (p - p^{(5/6) + \large \epsilon}) + (1 - p^{(1/6) - \large \epsilon}) \geq \epsilon$?

Comment: Show that the derivative of the left-hand-side with respect to $p$ is always positive, and then evaluate the left-hand-side at $p=3$.

Comment: When I derivate I get $1 - (5/6 + \epsilon) p^{\epsilon - 1/6} - (1/6 - \epsilon) p^{-\epsilon - 5/6}$. How do not know how to show that it is always positive. It does not seem easier than the original problem.

Comment: Use $1-(\frac56+\varepsilon)p^{-1/6+\varepsilon}-(\frac16-\varepsilon)p^{-5/6-{e} }\geq 1-p^{-1/6+\varepsilon}-\frac16 p^{-5/6-\varepsilon}\geq 1-3^{-1/6}-\frac16 3^{-4/6}$. Where does your problem come from and why do you want to solve it? What have you tried?

Comment: I have a $p + 1$ regular graph and its eigenvalues satisfy $|\mu| \leq p^{5/6 + \epsilon} + p^{1/6 - \epsilon}$. So, to show it is an expander I need to have the above property. You last inequality is incorrect. for instance, with $\epsilon = 1/7$, we have $1 - 3^{-1/6 + 1/7} - 1/6 \cdot 3^{-5/6 - 1/7} < 0$ but $1 - 3^{-1/6} - 1/6 \cdot 3^{-5/6} > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of the left-hand-side with respect to $p$ is $$1-(\frac56+\epsilon)p^{-1/6+\epsilon}-(\frac16-\epsilon)p^{-5/6-\epsilon}> 1-(\frac56+\epsilon)p^0-(\frac16-\epsilon)p^0=0.$$
Therefore the left-hand-side is strictly increasing, so it suffices to show that
$$3-3^{5/6+\epsilon}+1-3^{1/6-\epsilon}\geq 0 \iff 4- 3^{5/6+\epsilon}-3^{1/6-\epsilon}\geq 0.$$
To prove this inequality, note first that the derivative of the right-hand-side with respect to $\epsilon$, namely
$$(3^{1/6-\epsilon}-3^{5/6+\epsilon}) \log 3,$$
is negative, since $$3^{1/6-\epsilon}<3^{5/6+\epsilon}\iff 1/6-\epsilon<5/6+\epsilon\iff 0<4/6+2\epsilon$$
for all $\epsilon>0$. Thus it suffices to show that
$$4- 3^{5/6+1/6}-3^{1/6-1/6}\geq 0\iff 4-3-1\geq 0,$$
which of course is true, and we are done!